# how to hide username and password in Oracle JDBC driver connecting to ORACLE DB

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I have a `jsp page` which connects to `ORACLE DB` to retrieve data from a table.

```
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:port:mySID","user","admin");
```

I am using `oracle jdbc driver` to connect to DB with clear text password and username.

I want to encrypt or move away this clear txt passwords from my jsp page.

Comment: Create a three tier architecture.

Comment: Whatever application server you have to generate the JSP page most likely has options to configure connections where the passwords are not stored in clear text.

Comment: yes my application server has pwd stored in secure dir , but how do i access that username/password in my jsp page. In perl we will use below code to connect DB   `my $hostname = $ENV{"home"}; 

use lib "$ENV{dir}/common";

use CommonFunctions;

my $dbh = CommonFunctions::connect_DBI($hostname,"username","password");

CommonFunctions::disconnect_DBI($dbh);`

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create a data source inside your application server or servlet container.
It will depend upon which server you are using. There might be other steps involved like creating a resource reference in case of tomcat. Which server are you using?

Step2: Perform a jndi lookup from your application using sample code given below.
It is strongly recommended not to write Java inside jsp
pages(scripting). Use servlets or a frame work like spring MVC

...

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource datasource =         (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("datasource_name");
Connection conn = datasource.getConnection();
```

Comment: Application server: linux  and web server : tomcat_6.0.20